# Accessing VideoJS Played TimeRanges

Tags: html, reactjs, video, video.js

I'm building a web app using ReactJS that will allow employees to view various video training sessions and then answer quiz questions about them. I would like to use HTML5 video elements to maximize compatibility across devices, but users can always just scrub through the video to get to the end and trigger the next operation in the app. It is necessary for them to watch the entire video before moving on.

I need a way to tell if the whole video has been played before allowing the user to move on. I was looking at the [Video JS Advanced Examples](http://videojs.com/advanced/) page, and I found exactly what I was looking for. They have a 'played' data field that updates with what time ranges the user has played through. The problem is that I have no idea of how to implement that feature in my app. I can include and get VideoJS up and running just fine, but I don't know how to access the 'played' property of the video player.

If anyone could give me a direction to go in, I would really appreciate it. If this is a stupid question, I'm really sorry. I'm still fairly new to all of this. Thank you so much.

Cheers,

Jaydon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`played` comes form the [html5 media spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#dom-media-played). It returns a [TimeRanges object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#timeranges).
Video.js provides most of the functionality of the native video element via methods. So, the `played` property on the video element (as `vidEl.played`) becomes a method call on the Video.js's `player` object (as `player.played()`).

The API to time ranges is a bit weird. But essentially, it has a three properties: `length`, `start`, and `end`.
This is what they do:
* `length`: how many ranges are there? In the case of `played`, how many different sections of the video have been played?
* `start()`: a method that tells you the start time of a given range
* `end()`: a method that tells you the end time of a given range

It's likely that you will only have one range, but it's possible you'll have more. So, you'll want to loop over the length of the ranges. To know exactly how much the user as played, you'll basically want to loop over each range and calculate it's duration (`end(i) - start(i)` and then compare it to the duration of the video (`player.duration()`). If they are close, that means that the user has watched the entire video.

Comment: when I try to call the played method on player element I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: player.played is not a function" if I call currentTime() and duration() these all are returning proper values.